# Get part of the string using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

I've a strings, which can have a text like:

```
'some text user#t12# some text'
'username#John# some text'
'some text usersurname#Malks#'
'userphoto#1.jpg#'
```

How do I get a text between # and # symbols?

There's a typical structure of the part of the string to search for - `type#variable#`

`type` is a **JS variable** `type`, it's placed before the first `#`.

`variable` is a text that I need to get.

I'm searching for a regexp, that return `variable`, that is between `#...#`.

The problem is, I'm not too familiar with regexp, can you help me please?

Comment: I had a bad luck trying to code this myself.

Comment: @Steve if you know the exact position of each element, why do not use `split` function?

Comment: split is too expensive

Comment: @Steve `indexOf` + `substring` ?

Comment: split, for, indexof, etc instead of a simple match. Not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capture groups, basically in a regex anything in brackets will be part of the cpature group, in this case you want to capture all the characters between two hashes. The any amount of characters regex is .* so this is what you want to capture between two hashes. Once you execute it you will find the match as second in the array (the first will be the string with the hashes.

```
var type = "";
var myString = "some text user#t12# some text";
var myRegexp = new RegExp(type+"#(.*)#","g");
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  // t12
```

any other matches between hashes will be in match[2].. match[n]

Comment: I need to support `var1` variable, that is placed directly before the first #

Comment: Also, there can be multiple #...#, some may not be a part of the string I search for

Comment: can you give me an example of this? I do not understand

Comment: Example: `var type = something; /type#(.*)#/g`